# how to implement scroll by drag using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Given a div with preset height (say 200px) set to hide overflowing content,
and a child div with height of 600px,
I want to be able to scroll the content div using a drag action.

so that when a mouse down starts at some point and moves several pixels the content will scroll as well.

optimally I would like to have some "speed and friction" logic added to this behavior so that you could "toss" the content div and have if continue its movement past the drop point.

Does anyone know of such ready made functionality? in either JQuery / JQuery Ui or some plugin ?
if not the implementation idea would also be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following jquery plugin:
http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/

It is simple and there are things to desire about it,
 but it is very small and has the basic functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I like [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), though it has some problems with fixed positioning if that's an issue.

[Here's a live demo.](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/)

Comment: I am trying to use this and when I leave the mouse button it jumps back to the "zero" position. any Idea what I am missing? must the wrapper and scroller be both position absolute ?

Comment: @epeleg: I don't know. Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: sorry, Its too much code, and although I did see iScroll working on their sample, it just didn't work for me. as I wrote - I ended up using some other code that is a JQuery plugin.